# Source of iPhone weather data?

Tags: iphone

Where does the standard iPhone weather app get it's data from?

Specifically, is there a single global server or does it use local sources depending on your location?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Weather is from Yahoo. See the little icon on the lower left side:

[image]

Click it to view the Yahoo-Website. See [here](http://weather.yahoo.com/) for all Yahoo Weather-Services.

Also, the Stock information comes from Yahoo.

Comment: And interesting for developers; the weather API:
http://developer.yahoo.com/weather/